# JSON data pass to div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code and it won't work. I want to pass the JSON data to the HTML div tag through javascript.

This is a div tags what I want to import data

```
<div class="row mt-2 mb-2 height bg-dark text-light"  id="<?php echo $row['dev_ID']; ?>">
            <div class="col-3" >
                <div class="card height bg-dark" style="width: auto">
                    <div class="card-body" >
                        <h6 id="trname">Name : </h6>
                        <p id="trtype"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card height bg-dark" style="width: auto">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6>Status</h6>
                        <p ><p id="trstatus"></p><?php // echo $row['dev_Status']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="card height bg-dark" style="width: auto">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6>Reading 01</h6>
                        <p id="trreading01"><?php// echo $row['dev_Reading01']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="card height bg-dark" style="width: auto">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6>Reading 02</h6>
                        <p id="trreading02"><?php// echo $row['dev_Reading02']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="card height bg-dark" style="width: auto">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6>Dev</h6>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my javascript part.  I'm guessing I'll need to use AJAX or Jquery but I lack the knowledge on how to do so.

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',loadReadings);
    //load readings
      function loadReadings(){
          setInterval(function(){
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST','xhr.php',true);

          xhr.onload = function(){
              if(this.status == 200){
                  var obj =this.responseText;
                  console.log(this.responseText);
                  for (var key in obj){
                      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){

              var row = document.getElementById(obj[key].id);
            // innerHTML = property is useful for getting or replacing the content of HTML elements.
            row.div[1].innerHTML = obj[key].dev_type;
            row.trstatus[2].innerHTML = obj[key].status;
            row.trreading01[3].innerHTML = obj[key].reading01;
            row.trreading02[4].innerHTML = obj[key].reading02;




                      }
                  }

              }
          }
          xhr.send( )
          },1000);
      }
```

and also this is the php part.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb1";


$array = array();

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dmaster";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arraynew = array(
            'id'        =>$row["dID"],
            'dev_name'  =>$row["dName"],
            'dev_type'  =>$row["dType"],
            'access_code'  =>$row["access_Code"],
            'time_stamp'=>$row["time_Stamp"],
            'status'    =>$row["dStatus"],
            'reading01' =>$row["dReading01"],
            'reading02' =>$row["dReading02"]
        );
        $arraynew = array_map('htmlentities',$arraynew);
        array_push($array,$arraynew);
    }
} else {
    //echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

$json = html_entity_decode(json_encode($array));
echo "data: ".$json."\n\n";

ob_end_flush();
flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As i checked your code and found some of the issue kindly update

update in php file:

```
 echo "data: ".$json."\n\n";
 replace with only echo $json;
```

Update in javascript script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadReadings(){
              var xhr = null;
              if(window.ActiveXObject) { xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
              else if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
              if(xhr)
              {
                  xhr.open('POST','xhr.php',true);
                  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                         var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                         for (var key in obj){
                             if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){

                                var row = document.getElementById(obj[key].id);
                                console.log(row);
                                // innerHTML = property is useful for getting or replacing the content of HTML elements.
                                row.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].innerHTML = obj[key].dev_type;
                                document.getElementById('trstatus').innerHTML = obj[key].status;
                                document.getElementById('trreading01').innerHTML = obj[key].reading01;

                                document.getElementById('trreading02').innerHTML = obj[key].reading02;

                              }
                          }


                      }
                  }
                  xhr.send();
              }

          }
    </script>
```

Because in your script checked only by xhr status not readystate hence it will create issue when ajax request will fire , and one more thing you set the value by taking the reference of row var it okay for div but remaining all how already id so no need to take any of reference but if you are thinking , you may list multiple of dynamic info then define all to a class because by your current code ,your page will contain multiple of same ids which is not right

update in html:

as you bind a event with button id by you do not any button id to any of the tag
So add this line on your html code

```
 <button type="button" onclick="loadReadings()">Click here </button>
```